# Explicit CWinThread object deletion after Message Pump is quit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have derived my own thread class from CWinThread in MFC, and creating the object using the code mentioned below.

**Thread Creation:**

```
CMyOwnThread* thrd;
void CreateThread()
{
    thrd = new CMyOwnThread();
    thrd->CreateThread();
}
```

**Thread Termination:**

```
void DestroyThread()
{
    thrd->PostThreadMessage(WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

}
```

Now, do I need to explicitly delete the pointer "thrd" also ?
As thread would be destroyed after the message pump ceases to run.

Comment: yes, because thrd is created on head

Comment: What if, I create the thread using method: 
CMyOwnThread * thrd = AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyOwnThread));

Comment: then in that case use  AfxEndThread

Comment: No.  Set the m_bAutoDelete member the way you want it.  Default is TRUE so you don't have to delete yourself.